# Child Div's in Flex Container are uneven in % width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width, responsive

I have three DIVs in a flex container that need to stretch across evenly with a 40px margin AND be responsive as the screen width shrinks.  When I begin to shrink the size of the browser window, the middle DIV remains larger than the other two on the side.

How do keep all three child DIVs the same width as the screen width shrinks?

Here is my code:

```css
    .container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 65px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    }
    .child1, .child2, .child3 {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    padding-left: 70px;
    padding-right: 70px;
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    }
    .container > * + * {
    margin-left: 40px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="child1"> Child 1</div>
        <div class="child2"> Child 2</div>
        <div class="child3"> Child 3</div>
    </div>
```

Here is a screenshot.  The middle DIV is slightly bigger:

[image]

Comment: please add HTML code.

Comment: try adding `flex:1;` in all child classes.

Comment: Did not work to add flex:1

Answer (score 0):

The property you're looking for is flex-basis ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis)).

By default, flex-basis is based on the content, and it appears your content has different widths.

Specify the same flex-basis across all three child divs to ensure they remain the same size regardless of their content.